# Unity and Dash displayed under all active windows

Tags: unity, 12.10, unity-dash

When Ubuntu starts, the Unity toolbar is displayed at the background and all windows are displayed above it. When I hit the Super button on my keyboard, the Dash opens but remains at the background so it's unusable.
I found out that closing my session and re-opening a session fixes the problem. 
Does anyone have a better solution ? Seems like Unity/Compiz are starting on the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install myunity.
this is how:

- open terminal

type in, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:myunity/ppa`

type in, `sudo apt-get update`

type in, `sudo apt-get install myunity`

Then that is done, open up the dash and type myunity.

And it should come up as this, [image]

Then click the arrow that is Behavior, [image]

And click fixed. That is all, tell me if you have problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I cannot try this solution since MyUnity doesn't exist for Ubuntu 12.10 ... I'll try to find another app that allows to make the same configuration tweak (maybe Ubuntu Tweak ?)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214060/unity-in-12-10-comes-up-behind-other-windows). To be short: you need to disable and re-enable unity plugin in compiz settings manager. Al least it helped me (I'm using ATI opensource drivers).