# Application switcher disappears behind windows

Tags: 16.04, unity, application-switcher

Title says it all.

Instead of popping out *in front* of all the open windows, the task switcher is stuck in the back. At first, I thought it just didn't work - and then I closed some of the windows, I saw it was just kinda stuck in the back.

[image: Screenshot of switcher behind an application window in Ubuntu 16.04]

**EDIT 07.12.2017:** Tried the fixes in the comments and answer below, no cigar.

Comment: Do you have clean Ubuntu 16.04 installation?

Comment: @j123b567 that I do indeed. Also, that's a catch-all. Try something more specific if you may:)

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/214060/unity-in-12-10-comes-up-behind-other-windows
this may work for you !

Comment: I've just started getting this same problem, a screenshot is tricky - as alt+printscreen whilst already holding alt+tab behaves a bit strangely.

Comment: I've edited in the best screenshot I could get - note this is not the OP's system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by using [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/). Go to `Window Management` and enable `Application Switcher`. By doing so I got a popup telling me that there were conflicting bindings with another plugin. Click `Resolve conflicts`, and `set x anyway` on the following dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the cause - but a reboot fixed it for me. I'm sure lighter-weight solutions must be possible.

Looking forward to someone providing a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue several times, including just this morning.

Based on the discussion here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860967, I tried `unity --replace` from the command line.

The good news is that it fixed the issue; the bad news is it's only a bit less drastic than logging out or rebooting; it immediately killed almost all my GUI apps (only gedit and the terminal window remained).

Incidentally, there was a somewhat nonsensical message in the terminal: `WARNING: This is for compatibility with other desktop interfaces please use unity without --replace`.

I have no idea what that means, or what we should type instead. But this command did put my task switcher back on top.